# Angular RouteLinkActive for child components not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, router

i have Component IndexSettings with childs Component, I need when they go to the child component so that the asset class works, but it disappears, can you know what is the reason? thanks for the help

Index Settings Component Routes

```
    children: [
      {
        path: 'settings',
        component: SettingsIndexComponent,
        children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'company-details', pathMatch: 'full' },
          {
            path: 'company-details',
            component: CompanyDetailsComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'team',
            component: TeamComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'password',
            component: PasswordComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'plans-pricing',
            component: PlansPricingComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'payments-billing',
            component: PaymentsBillingComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'documents',
            component: DocumentsComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'notifications',
            component: NotificationsComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
```

Html routeLinkActive

```
      <a
        [routerLink]="['/dashboard/settings']" [routerLinkActive]="['sidebar-active']"  [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"
         class="list-group-item border-0 d-inline-block ps-4 custom-nav-item mt-2">
        <i class="fa-light fa-sliders-simple custom-nav-item"></i>
        <span class="ps-2 custom-nav-item">Settings</span>
      </a>
```

Comment: when does it disappear?

Comment: if come /dashboard/settings its okey, and come childer example /dashboard/settings/company-details, disappears sidebar-active class in sidebar.

Comment: if you need more information or when to understand what the problems are, please ask.

Comment: What happens if you remove the active tag? Looking at the docs (https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) it looks like with the active tag it will only show as active IF AND ONLY IF the URL is /dashboard/settings.

Comment: `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"`, it only add the "sidebar-active" lass when current url is exact match with "/dashboard/settings". If you want this class to be added when current url is the child path of "/dashboard/settings" (example: "/dashboard/settings/..."), then consider removing the `[routerLinkActiveOptions]` attribute

Comment: @YongShun Thank you, i remove ```[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}" ``` it started working! :)